# How to set a api endpoint for json in windows?

Tags: json, windows, api

I am looking for a solution to set a api end point for the json file in windows. This json should show the updated value whenever it get updated.
Can anyone help to suggest for the right approach?
Thank you

Comment: start here: https://www.iis.net/ Then if you need to run code to respond to the API request, and not just return a static JSON file: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis

Answer (score 0):

there are a million ways to do it ([nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), [apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi), [lighthttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/), [IIS](https://www.iis.net/), even a simple netcat server could do it, to mention a few), but
the simplest way i can think of is to just host the json file from [HFS](https://www.rejetto.com/hfs/?f=dl)
(a simple HTTP file server that runs as a single stand-alone exe, and requires no installation, and is free and open source)